# access info of the instance from instance function

Tags: javascript, scope

I have this simple code:

```
function fetch(callback) {
    const data = [1, 2, 3];//from query to server
    callback(data);
    callback.prototype.log.call(); // PROBLEM HERE. I want to log the fetchCallback instance data array from here
}

function fetchCallback() {
    this.data = []
}

fetchCallback.prototype.store = function(data) {
    data.forEach(el => this.data.push(el));
    console.log(this.data);  //here the log works because of the instance binding
}

fetchCallback.prototype.log = function() {
    console.log(this.data);
}

const mycallback = new fetchCallback();
fetch(mycallback.store.bind(mycallback));
```

In `function fetch(callback) {...}` I want to be able to access the callback holder instance, which is `mycallback` to log the `this.data` of **that** instance. I tried `callback.prototype.log.call();`, `callback.log();`, and some others, but I am missing something regarding the scope/context topic.

Edit:

This seems to work if the whole instance is passed through:

```
function fetch(callback) {
    const data = [1, 2, 3];//from query to server
    callback.store(data);
    callback.log();
}

const mycallback = new fetchCallback();
//fetch(mycallback.store.bind(mycallback));
fetch(mycallback);
```

Edit2: Data hold and store functions separated

```
function fetch(callback, dataHolder) {
    const data = [1, 2, 3];//from query to server
    callback(data, dataHolder);
    log(dataHolder.data);
}

function dataHolder() {
    this.data = []
}

function store(data, holder) {
    data.forEach(el => holder.data.push(el));
    //console.log(this.data);
}

function log(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

const myDataHolder = new dataHolder();
//fetch(mycallback.store.bind(mycallback));
fetch(store, myDataHolder);
```

Comment: The problem is that you're not passing `mycallback` (which isn't actually a callback function, but an instance object) but rather `store` as a callback function. You *cannot* access the instance from that, all you can do with it is to call it (`callback(data)`).

Comment: All of this is very unidiomatic. Can you share your real code so that we could suggest the proper approach?

Comment: the real code is quite more complicated, this simplified case represent what happens in the code accurately. I fetch some data, which I store with the callback function, then I need to use that data to draw a plot or a grafic, what would be the log of this example, meaning that I need to acces the data retrieved from the fetch to paint a plot in the client

Comment: if the whole instance if passed through, it works. Updated question.  To the , "you're not passing mycallback (which isn't actually a callback function, but an instance object) but rather store as a callback function", as I am binding the instance, I thought I could get to the instance somehow to get to the instance info...

Comment: No, you can't get the instance from the bound method. If you want to call multiple methods individually, just pass the instance itself. But the idiomatic solution would be to not have `fetch` deal with logging - instead just do `fetch(data => { mycallback.store(data); mycallback.log(); })`. And stop calling your "class" `fetchCallback` or your instance `mycallback`, since they're not callback functions. I don't know what they do in your actual code, but in the code you've shown the only responsibility of that class is to be a `DataHolder`. Or maybe you don't need a class at all.

Comment: As you say that is exactly what it is, a `DataHolder`. The point is that the `DataHolder` class has got the methods that I call `fetchCallbacks`, that are called after the fetch, so that the `DataHolder` "class" absorbs the info. Doesnt that make sense?

Comment: More concretely the fetchCallback is called inside an ajax `.done(function(data) { callback(data) }`

Comment: But are you using the `DataHolder` instance from anywhere else than right when the fetch call finished? Does it have any other state than the data? Then you should not use a class. Just write a procedure that does something with data, and use that as the callback.

Comment: Your convention is not quite correct and misleading. `function fetch(callback)` the callback is actually an Object instance. Look like you are in a wrong direction to appraoch something. We usually name callback as a callback function

Comment: @Bergi `DataHolder` instance from anywhere else than right when the fetch call finished? -> no, just to absorb the data after the fetch, or fetches if the fetch is done in many steps. Thanks I see your point

Comment: I guess that what is being suggested in the comments is that the Data hold and store functions should be separated, and the data holder instance and the callback should passed arround independently like in the working edited answer. I thought my approach could be cleaner soas to operate with one object to be passed around in the operation, but I am not familiar with js, and the context/this topic. Your comments or suggested approaches for this are appreciated

Comment: check "Edit2: Data hold and store functions separated" code to check what I am referring to